# Why does a button not fire when clicked through cypress in a nuxt web app?

Tags: nuxt.js, cypress

I have a button component in a Nuxt.js web app. The button component emits a `click` event when it is clicked. I use that button component on a Nuxt page and provide a page method as an event handler. When I click that button manually, the event is triggered and the application flow continues as expected. This is my code:

```html
<MyButton id="button" @click="openModal()">
  {{ $t('open') }}
</MyButton>
```

However, when I click the same button using Cypress, nothing happens at all and the event handler is not called:

```js
cy.get('#button').click()
```

After the test fails, I can press the button (in Cypress) manually and it will work. This led my to this blog post suggesting a race condition: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/22/when-can-the-test-click/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blog post is indeed correct, this is a race condition. The button gets rendered server-side and sent to the browser. Cypress waits for the page to load but it doesn't know to also wait for the [hydration](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html). So the event handler is attached by some client-side code. Cypress is too fast here and clicks the button before the event handler is attached. That's also why it always works manually. Additionally, the `click()` method of cypress will [not be retried automatically](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability#Not-every-command-is-retried) so the test will just fail.

So basically, we'd want to wait on some signal from Nuxt that it is done hydrating. Unfortunately, I didn't find an API to do that. The best solution I came up with is adding a class to your layout to signal readiness and wait for that in Cypress:

```html
<template>
  <div :class="['default-layout', hydrated ? 'hydrated' : 'hydrating']">
    <nuxt />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DefaultLayout',
  data () {
    return {
      hydrated: false,
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.hydrated = true
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Then in `cypress/support/commands.ts` you can add a custom command to wait for the `hydrated` class:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('waitForHydration', (timeout: number = 20_000) => {
  cy.log('Waiting for hydration ...')
  cy.get('.default-layout.hydrated', { log: false, timeout })
})
```

If you're using typescript, add the typings in `cypress/support/index.d.ts`:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    waitForHydration(timeout?: number): Chainable<void>
  }
}
```

And finally, in your test suite, use it like this:

```js
it('can click the button', () => {
  cy.visit('/')
  cy.waitForHydration()
  cy.get('#button').click()
})
```